# ASCII/count printing C program?

Tags: c

I am trying to make a program that will read characters from standard input until EOF (the end-of-file mark) is read.

And after that function I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>



int main(int agc, char *agv[]) {
  int x;
  int count = 0;

    while ((x = getchar()) != EOF){
  count++;
```

Comment: Honestly @BLUEPIXY, that's rude. I may not be up to par with anyone here but I am trying to get through the curriculum of intro to CS without having to waste money and credits, taking the class so I need extra help, I have an intro book and getting through it without a lecturer is sort of difficult. So thanks for your lack of help.

Comment: i'd recommend youtube videos.  there's a lot of good programming tutorial videos.  usually the questions here are very specific, so your post is a little out there...

Comment: It's repeating the question by deleted without considering the comments and answers to the questions it is rude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `main()`, the lines marked are function declarations, not function calls. You will probably need to replace them with calls to the functions.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int x;
    int count = 0;

    while ((x = getchar()) != EOF){
        count++;
    }
    prHeader(FILE *out); // Declaration
    prCountStr(FILE *out, int code, char *str, int count); // Declaration
    prCountChr(FILE *out, int code, char chr, int count); // Declaration
    prTotal(FILE *out, int count); // Declaration
    return 0;
}
```

You are also going to need to have an array (`counters`, for sake of argument) of 256 integers, all initialized to zero, and your loop will increment the entry in `counters` corresponding to the character just read.  Fortunately, `getchar()` returns a positive value for every possible input character.

In C, you should seldom define a function in a header; in your case, you should not define the functions in a header.  The declarations should be there, but the definitions should not be there.  You should have another source file, presumably `common.c`, which defines the functions.  You would then need to compile both the file containing the `main()` function and `common.c`, and you'd need to link both object files to create the program.  (In the short term, you can avoid that by leaving the functions in the header and simply compiling the code that defines the `main()` function, but that is subverting the point of a header file.)  The majority of the variable definitions should be in `common.c` and not in `common.h` too.

You have other work to do too; the BADFILE and related macros are not yet used.  It also appears you might need to parse the command line options.